# Configuring MSBuild Path in Jenkins inside docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, msbuild

My jenkins container is inside the docker. Since Docker is linux based it is not accepting any path like "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe".

What will be the msbuild path for jenkins inside docker container?

I am getting error like "FATAL: Unable to use this plugin on this kind of operation system"

Answer (score 2):

Instead use windowsservercore docker image with MSBuild.
Docker also support linux and windows platform.
For detailed info about the windows docker image refer below link.

https://blog.alexellis.io/3-steps-to-msbuild-with-docker/

Comment: no, either you need to use above image or use remote agent from docker linux to windows for MSBuild execution.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71bcb26b-3149-41c7-9ad7-fe908ffe983e/msbuild-on-linux?forum=msbuild